# SQL Server - INSERT INTO overwrites existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a weird problem here, I am trying to load some data into a new table in SQL Server. The table has few million records since 2015 to till date. When I try to load entire data, it runs for about 2 hrs before it stops and throws an error

> Transaction log - Full.

So what I'm trying to do is break the time frame into 2 parts in `WHERE` clause
`YEAR >= 2016` and insert values and then modify the `INSERT` statement to 
`YEAR >= 2015 AND YEAR < 2016`. When I run this, it overwrites the existing 2016 data but not the 2017 data. So basically entire 2016 returns nothing.

Am I missing something?

It's really annoying as I end up spending hours just loading data.

Code

```
INSERT INTO <tablename>
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT <columnnames> 
         FROM <few join statements> 
         WHERE <calendaryear >= 2016
         GROUP BY <statements>) a -- this loads data from 2016 to present.

INSERT INTO <tablename>
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT <columnnames> 
         FROM <few join statements> 
         WHERE <calendaryear >= 2015 AND calendaryear < 2016 
    GROUP BY <statements>) a --this loads data from 2015 to 2016
```

After executing the second statement the former one gets overwritten. Here I have shown as 2 separate queries but in actual I just comment out the calendaryear statements and run as 2 separate queries.

Thanks.

Comment: Set your recovery mode to simple recovery.  That should help with the log overflows.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's my DBA's job I can't do that. My concern is with the query itself.

Comment: If you are using `INSERT INTO`, then _it overwrites the existing 2016 data but not the 2017 data_ makes no sense. Have you checked that you have 2016 data in target table prior to running the insert of `2015<= year and year < 2016`?

Comment: Can you share what queries you are running?

Comment: Updated my question with query @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: INSERT only inserts records. It never 'overwrites'. Only an UPDATE does that. So I think there is some misunderstanding here. What SELECT statement are you using to identify that it is overwritten? What do record counts tell you? Perhaps to simplify you should just use `=` and load one year at a time

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I know, I'm working on it right now and I'm basically trying to INSERT values from 5 different tables INTO a single table using JOINS. My next POA is this, I will run query thrice once with CY = 2017 (loads 2017 data), then CY=2016 (loads 2016 data  and keeps previous ones) finally CY = 2015 (loads 2015 data and keeps previous ones). Not a smartest way but I hope this works. Thoughts?

Comment: That way looks fine to me - you know exactly what you're inserting. Normally with a data migration you do things like check counts before and after, and save those results to a log (just a text file) so you have a record of how many records were inserted etc. Your original problem is still unclear though.

Comment: I'm keeping record of count, even I am stumbled. It never occured to me until I realized that 2016 data is missing but not 2017.

Comment: Can you post the literal query you're running? If you need to fake object names that's fine, but somehow I feel like there's a detail that's not being communicated.

Comment: You still haven't managed to explain - try and understand it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the former statement was never committed?  A rollback happened before the second statement?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Is there a possibility? I'm actually working within a sandbox in Production server.

Comment: Unless you're explicitly using a transact statement, If the first statement fills the logs up, an error would be generated and, the first statement would roll back.  The second statement would run successfully provided it didn't also cause the logs to fill.  I think you need to discover a way to bypass the logs or ask your dba to increase the log size  or you'll be forever trying to break your query up into small enough chunks.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I worked with SQL Server but I believe the command BCP (bulk loading) will bypass the logs.  You shouldn't need a DBA for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
USE [YOUR_DB]
GO

SELECT log_reuse_wait,log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.database
```

This should give you a clue as to why the log file is filling up.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414(v=sql.105).aspx